# How do I run Jenkins with a specific working directory and a specific user account?

Tags: rhel, java, jenkins

I am executing below jenkins.war with below command

```
  jenkins -jar jenkins.war
```

But I want to specify to use below path while executing the war

```
 `/data/jenkins`
```

and it should run as `jenkins` user . Right now it is getting executed as `root` user and under `/root` directory

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Did you create the user `jenkins`?

Comment: Also, did you create `/data` dir?

Answer (score 0):

I used environmental variables as below in script

JENKINS_HOME="/data/jenkins"
JENKINS_WAR="/data/jenkins/jenkins.war"

and passed them to Java with -D option

java -DJENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME -jar $JENKINS_WAR

```
# ps -ef | grep java
root         5     1  0 Mar19 ?        00:05:10 /apps/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java  -DJENKINS_HOME=/data/jenkins -jar /data/jenkins/jenkins.war
```

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins wiki discusses setting it up as a Unix daemon: [Installing Jenkins as a Unix daemon](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Unix+daemon). You have an RHEL tag in the question, and since RHEL 7 makes use of `systemd`, you could set up Jenkins to run as a `systemd` service. The steps to do this are shown below.

1. First, you'll need to download the Jenkins WAR file and place it somewhere. I chose the location `/opt/jenkins/jenkins.war`.
2. Next, you'll need to create/prepare the data directory you want to use, which is `/data/jenkins`.
3. You can now create a system user account with the name `jenkins`:

   ```
   useradd -r jenkins
   ```
4. Next, change the ownership of the Jenkins WAR file and data directory to this new user:

   ```
   chown -R jenkins:jenkins /opt/jenkins/
   chown -R jenkins:jenkins /data/jenkins/
   ```
5. Next, define the `systemd` service by creating a new unit file:

   ```
   vi /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service

   [Unit]
   Description=Jenkins Daemon

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/bin/java -jar /opt/jenkins/jenkins.war
   User=jenkins
   Environment=JENKINS_HOME=/data/jenkins

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
6. Make `systemd` aware of the new unit by reloading it:

   ```
   systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
7. Finally, start Jenkins:

   ```
   systemctl start jenkins
   ```

You should now be able to access Jenkins on port 8080. If `firewalld` is active, you'll need to allow the port by running `firewall-cmd --add-port=8080/tcp` on the system.

The Jenkins logs can now be seen with `journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=jenkins.service`. Running `ps -ef | grep jenkins` will show that it's running as the `jenkins` user:

```
jenkins   1749     1  7 11:04 ?        00:00:35 /bin/java -jar /opt/jenkins/jenkins.war
```

As an added bonus, run `systemctl enable jenkins` if you want the Jenkins service to be automatically started on system boot.